# Weird Moment.js format issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs, daterangepicker

I'm not sure if it is really a moment.js issue, but here it is. From the date range widget, I picked a date time of '03-01-2015 12:00 AM - 04-30-2015 11:59 PM'. The startDate and endDate, both are moment objects, passed to the callback function seem to be correct based on the first two lines output by console.log. However, if I create a new moment instance based on startDate.valueOf() and print out the formatted date string again, the new moment object displays a different timestamp (one hour ahead.) Here is the code snippet:

```
this._daterangepicker = this.$('#dateTimeRange').daterangepicker({
   timePicker           : true,
   timePickerIncrement  : 1,
   format               : 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
}, function(startDate, endDate, label) {
  let searchController = self.get('controller');

  console.log(`time picker date start ${startDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A')}`);
  console.log(`time picker date end ${endDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A')}`);

  console.log(`time picker reformat date start ${moment(startDate.valueOf()).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A')}`);
  console.log(`time picker reformat date end ${moment(endDate.valueOf()).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A')}`);

  console.log(`original ${startDate.valueOf()} - reformat ${moment(startDate.valueOf()).valueOf()}`);
});
```

Here is the output:

```
time picker date start 03-01-2015 12:00 AM
time picker date end 04-30-2015 11:59 PM
time picker reformat date start 02-28-2015 11:00 PM
time picker reformat date end 04-30-2015 11:59 PM
original 1425193200000 - reformat 1425193200000
```

I'd expect start date to stay as '03-01-2015 12:00 AM', but it is now '02-28-2015 11:00 PM'. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing that it is a timezone issue. The date returned by `daterangepicker` probably is Timezone aware and that offset is lost when you convert it to a number and back to a Moment.js date (which is in UTC).